# Calculating Area of Curve using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate Area For a given curve y = f(x) between the limits l and r.

```
  Input will be : l r [a1,a2,a3..] [b1,b2,b3,b4,..]
  The curve will be (a1)x^(b1) + (a2)x^(b2)+....
```

My program:

```
  area_curve _ _ [] [] = 0 
  area_curve l r (ai:as) (bi:bs) = (ai(r^^(bi+1)-l^^(bi+1))) + area_curve l r as bs
```

When I run the program I am getting the following error:

> ```
> "ghci> " area_curve 1 4 [1,2,3,4,5] [6,7,8,9,10]
> <interactive>:20:1:
>     Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a1 -> a)
>     (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>     When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
>       it :: forall a a1. (Fractional a1, Num a, Num (a1 -> a)) => a
> ```

Comment: This is project Eluler?

Comment: there seems to be some `*` missing (for example here: `ai(r^^...)` ... you know mathematicians are so lazy the don't even write the `*` / `\cdot` ;)

Comment: Multiplication needs to be explicit. `ai*(r^^ ...`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I found this at hackerrank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

break down to easy pieces

```
powers x = map (x^)
dot = zipWith (*)
minus = zipWith (-)

curve x as ps = dot as $ powers x ps

areacurve le ri as ps = minus (curve ri as ps) (curve le as ps)
```

**UPDATE:**
Note that I just refactored your code, didn't really looked into what it does.  If you want to evaluate integrals of the curves here is a more structured way

assume powers are non-negative, I'll simplify it by fixing numerical type as Double but should be easy to generalize

```
type Curve = [(Double,Double)]

parabola = [(1.0,2.0)] 
line     = [(1.0,1.0)] 
zero     = []  

integral :: Curve -> Curve
integral = map (\(a,p) -> (a/(p+1),p+1))

eval :: Double -> Curve -> Double
eval :: Double -> Curve -> Double
eval x c = sum $ map (\(a,p) -> a*x**p) c
```

Now for example, the area under the curve of `3*x^2+1` for `2<x<3`

```
> curve = [(1.0,1.0),(3.0,2.0)]
> integral curve
[(0.5,2.0),(1.0,3.0)]

>  map ($ integral curve) $ map eval [2,3]
[10.0,31.5]
```

the area is the difference between these two values 21.5

Similarly, you can define the area between two curves.

Comment: I guess you have to `sum` the list as well.

Comment: I did that but need an even good estimation of the area of the curve.

Comment: I tried by using the limit definition of integral with sub interval length 0.001 .

Comment: you can do the symbolical integration and evaluate at the end.  For the curves with non-negative powers there is no need for numerical integration.  I reworked the code please check.

Comment: Splitting up code in small tasks is nice and fine, but `powers`, `dot` and `minus` are hardly more descriptive, nor significantly shorter than their definition. I'd not give them names of their own. If you do, then at least give them signatures! (Also @v.sharathchandra: _always give your top-level definitions type signatures._)